# Which IDEs are easiest to write plugins for?

Tags: plugins, editor

- Atom calls itself "a hackable text editor", and Nuclide turns it into an IDE.  How does it stack up to this promise?
- The JetBrains suite (IntelliJ, PyCharm, etc.) seem to have a lot of plugins.  How easy are they to write compared to other IDEs?
- A decade ago, plugin development for Eclipse had a reputation for being unwieldy.  Has the situation improved?
- Any other IDE I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

My preference would be Atom as it is powered by Github and has a very welcoming community for Open-Source contributors.

It has a vast variety of plugins and I frequently use its C++ plugin to build my code.

[Creating A simple Package in Atom](https://blog.eleven-labs.com/en/create-atom-package/)

[Simple Tutorial for making Plugins for Atom](https://blog.github.com/2016-08-19-building-your-first-atom-plugin/)

Anyway these are my preferences :)